# Can't delete dynamically generated columns (as variables) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Having trouble deleting a column that was generated dynamically. I'm new to pandas (and python) and modifying an existing pandas library, so if the code looks half competent and half insane that's why.

```
def _get_macd_c(df, f, s, g):
    fast = df['close_'+str(f)+'_ema']
    slow = df['close_'+str(s)+'_ema']
    df['macd'] = fast - slow
    df['macds'] = df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
    df['macdh'] = (df['macd'] - df['macds'])
    del df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
    del fast
    del slow
```

The columns *represented by the variables** 'fast' and 'slow' persist on the df obj. Why?

If the string was not dynamic `df['close_10_ema']` (as it was originally), it's a non-issue. I'm unclear on why this change makes the variable representing the column undeletable.

Comment: @ the (now deleted) comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, but the drop command didn't work, the "name" of the column isn't "fast"/"slow", it's `close_#_ema`, but even changed the argument `axis` throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `del fast` and `del slow` then delete `Series` not columns.

So for remove columns with columns names `fast`, `slow`, `macd_'+str(g)+'_ema` need:

```
del df['fast']
del df['slow']
del df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
```

But for drop multiple columns is better use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop(['fast','slow','macd_'+str(g)+'_ema'], axis=1)
```

In your function better is dont create new columns and then delete them:

```
def _get_macd_c(df, f, s, g):

    #subtract 2 columns to Series macd
    macd = df['close_'+str(f)+'_ema'] - df['close_'+str(s)+'_ema']
    df['macdh'] = macd - df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
    #if need remove column
    df = df.drop('macd_'+str(g)+'_ema', axis=1) 
    return df
```

I try to rewrite your function:

```
def _get_macd_c(df, f, s, g):
    colf = 'close_'+str(f)+'_ema'
    cols = 'close_'+str(s)+'_ema'
    colg = 'macd_'+str(g)+'_ema'

    df['macd'] = df[colf] - df[cols]
    df['macds'] = df[colg]
    df['macdh'] = (df['macd'] - df['macds'])
    df = df.drop([colf, cols, colg], axis=1)
    return df
```

Comment: I see that I can delete the column if I call it by name (ie `del df['name']`), Do you know why the variable referencing that column won't delete if it's name is referenced dynamically?

Comment: I think it is different object, so dont need it. it is like `a = 10` and then want delete `a`. It is not necessary. But if want delete column, then need `del` or `drop`.

Comment: in your example, making `macd` (line 3) would create two additional columns called 'close_x_ema' and 'close_y_ema', these are essential what i'm deleting.

Comment: I think no, I select column, because right side of `=`. But if use left side `=` like `df['something'] = 1` then create new column `something`

Comment: And I create helper Series `macd` for better readable code only.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks, but I dont and didnt think it, because I think it is clear between us ;) And if I dont agree with somebody, I dont downvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to go about this is to not delete the column by reference/variable but by name. I'm still unclear on why that is. Happy to mark an explanation for this as the correct answer, my solution feels a bit hack.

```
def _get_macd_c(df, f, s, g):
    fast = df['close_'+str(f)+'_ema']
    slow = df['close_'+str(s)+'_ema']
    df['macd'] = fast - slow
    df['macds'] = df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
    df['macdh'] = (df['macd'] - df['macds'])
    del df['macd_'+str(g)+'_ema']
    del df['close_'+str(f)+'_ema']
    del df['close_'+str(s)+'_ema']
```

Comment: Please check my last edit, I try rewrite your function.